# How to toggle orientation lock in android?

Tags: java, android, orientation

I want to create checkbox in my preference Activity that allows user to toggle orientation change.

In similar questions people write only about complete orientation lock (by overriding onConfigurationChanged method or adding configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml) or orientation enforcing ( by setRequestedOrientation ).

Is there a way to toggle orientation lock?

---

EDIT:
I've created a method that sets preferred orientation to one of three states: landscape, portrait and sensor. This method is used in conjunction with retrieving orientation `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)` and saving retrieved orientation into preferences. Then in activity that needs to lock orientation I fire this method with preferred orientation from preferences.

```
private static void setActivityOrientation(Activity activity, int preferenceOrientation) {
    if (preferenceOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { 
        if( activity.getRequestedOrientation() != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){ 
        // You need to check if your desired orientation isn't already set because setting orientation restarts your Activity which takes long
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    } else if (preferenceOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if( activity.getRequestedOrientation() != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }    
    } else {
        if( activity.getRequestedOrientation() != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR){
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand what is the problem with the setRequestedOrientation.

The SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR combine to landscape or portrait seem what you want, no?

```
if(....)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
else if(....)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
else if(....)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is bit more complicated. I want to be able to lock orientation. Example: If user wants to lock orientation in my application I read getResources().getConfiguration().orientation and then fire setRequestedOrientation to read current orientation. When he wants to disable lock I just setRequestedOrientation to ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR. Your answer helped me to realize it so I accept it.

Comment: @pixel did you figure out reverse orientations? I'm having the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock