# SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE upside down - Why?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation

I am using the following code to set orientation locking per user preference:

```
 private void doLock(boolean locked) {
     if (locked) {
       int o = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
       if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);       
       else if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);       
     } 
     else {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
     }
 }
```

It works, except for the case in which I am in unlocked mode (`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`) with the screen showing `LANDSCAPE` correctly (!), then invoke `doLock(true)` and...

instead of the screen locking to `LANDSCAPE` in its current (correct) landscape view, it locks to an **upside down** landscape view. i.e. same exact but flip vertically (`y` becomes `-y`).

Why is that and how do I approach this problem in order to fix it?

My initial inquiry reveals that there are [quite a few](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation) possibilities other than the common two (`portrait`, `landscape`), including `reverseLandscape`, but my hunch tells me that this problem may be [device-dependent](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html) and so by using it I might be fixing the problem only for my phone but not for all other devices.

Is there a way to force correct `landscape` orientation (when switched from `sensor`) in all devices?

To make this clearer and easier to reproduce, here are the steps that exhibit the problem:

1. Start with phone rotated to the right (**clockwise**), in unlocked mode (`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`) with the screen showing `LANDSCAPE` correctly (!),
2. Then invoke `doLock(true)`
3. Instead of the screen locking to `LANDSCAPE` in its current (correct) landscape view, it locks to an **upside down** landscape view. i.e. same exact but flip vertically (`y` becomes `-y`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is not a bug but rather the expected behavior from Android 2.2 or lower.

@forgivegod provided a theoretically correct approach, except that for Android 2.2 or lower the `screenOrientation.reverseLandscape` and `screenOrientation.reversePortrait` values are not recognized, even if faked (as @forgivegod's code does).

I bet you are seeing this problem when you rotate the phone clockwise (rotation=3) but not counter-clockwise (rotation=1).

Try with Android 2.3 or higher and see what happens.

Comment: OMG you are right! When I rotate the phone left, then lock it into `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` it works fine. When I rotate the phone right and do the same, of course it remains in `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`. When I rotate the phone right, then lock it into `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` it actually does **portrait!**. Looks like it's being ignored in Froyo. I tried the same exact thing with Gingerbread and it doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: @an00b Glad I could help. Also note that `activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()` gets fixed in `onCreate()`. That is, in `onResume()` you will still get the value that was retrieved in `onCreate()`, even if you rotated the phone just before the  `onResume()`.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following to disable and enable orientation via code (this will work in API level 7 and up) :

```
public static void disableRotation(Activity activity) {
    final int orientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    final int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getOrientation();

    // Copied from Android docs, since we don't have these values in Froyo
    // 2.2
    int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = 8;
    int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT = 9;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }

    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
}

public static void enableRotation(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. However, your code exhibits **the same exact** problem that I am describing above. I am still puzzled.

Comment: out of curiousity,  what happens when you change your doLock(true) to just " activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);"   is it still reverse landscape?

Comment: You should change to landscape when orientation is portrait and vice versa.

Answer (score 8):

**Simple and functional>**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    </activity>

  </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

try with universal landscape orientation

```
private static final int ORIENTATION_90 = 1;
private static final int ORIENTATION_0 = 0;
private static final int ORIENTATION_180 = 2;
private static final int ORIENTATION_270 = 3;

switch (orientation)
    {
      default:
      case ORIENTATION_0: // Portrait
        //dostuff
        break;
      case ORIENTATION_90: // Landscape left
        //do stuff
        break;
      case ORIENTATION_180: // Upside down.
        //do stuff
        break;
      case ORIENTATION_270: // Landscape right
        //do stuff
        break;
      }
```