# Rotating phone quickly 180 degrees, camera preview turns upside down

Tags: android, camera, rotation, android-camera, android-orientation

I have a custom camera application. When I rotating the phone by 90, camera preview works fine. But when I rotate phone quickly 180 degree, camera preview turns upside down. Is there any solution...

Here is my code below:

```
public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
private Sensor mOrientaion1;
int cameraId = 0;
public final String TAG = "CustomCamera";
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mOrientaion1 = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgError);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    Button btn1 = (Button) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Button btn2 = (Button) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.Button02);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "1111111111111111111111111",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            Constant.rotationValueForCamera = Constant.rotationValue;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "22222222222222222222222222",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

            Constant.imagePickerStatus = 0;

            Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

            finish();
        }
    });

    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == ot) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("ori1111", "land");
    } else {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("ori111", "port");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        findViewById(R.id.Button01).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.Button02).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("ori", "land");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        findViewById(R.id.Button01).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.Button02).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("ori", "port");
    }
}

public String getPollDeviceAttitude() {

    return Constant.rotationValueForCamera;
}

private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    if (Constant.isCapturedOk) {
        Constant.isCapturedOk = false;

        finish();
    }

}

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Log.e("Camrera", "22222222222222222");
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inDither = false;
        // bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bfo.inPurgeable = true;
        bfo.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PreviewActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra("data", data);
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                data.length, bfo);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (Constant.result == 180) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        if (Constant.result == 270) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        }
        int height = bitmapPicture.getHeight();
        int width = bitmapPicture.getWidth();
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,
                height, width, true);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Log.e("Camrera1", "22222222222222222");
        rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,
                50 /* ignored for PNG */, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
        Constant.imageData = bitmapdata;
        Log.e("Camrera2", "22222222222222222");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    if (previewing) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, cameraId, camera);
            previewing = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        Constant.result = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        Constant.result = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        Constant.result = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        Constant.result = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Log.e("Tab", "Stoping");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}

[image: App crashes image]

Comment: solution: don't do that.
it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @Nikola, so there is no solution for this problem?

Comment: maybe, i just don't think it has anything to do with your code.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059447/screen-orientation-landscape-upside-down-why

Comment: @AlexCohn, Thank you for your response. But it's not working for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Camera rotated directly and fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976859/camera-rotated-directly-and-fast)

Comment: Do you even receive the `surfaceChanged()` callback when you quickly rotate from landscape to landscape?

Comment: @AlexCohn, i don't know.

Comment: Please add a log message there. I suspect that your phone simply ignores the fast rotation and does not restart the surface. If that's what is happening, you must check the orientation sensor yourself, and restart, and not rely on `surfaceChanged()`.

Comment: @AlexCohn, It can not receive the surfaceChange() callback when you quickly rotate from landscape to landscape. Now what can i do. Please Help me...

Comment: @AlexCohn, please help me. Your Assumption is right. Now how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you slowly put the phone (landscape) flat on the table, then slowly pick it up reverse landscape, does you surface rotate correctly?

Comment: Open calculator, show it in landscape mode, quickly rotate it to reverse landscape. Does the screen show upside down?

Comment: @AlexCohn,If I slowly put the phone (landscape) flat on the table, then slowly pick it up reverse landscape, surface not rotate correctly.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I opened calculator, saw it in landscape mode, then quickly rotate it to reverse landscape, the screen not upside down. It was correct.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I am waiting for your answer brother.

Comment: Yes, I reduced your app to minimum, and I too see that 180° rotation does not trigger the expected event. Digging.

Comment: So @AlexCohn, is there any solution? Please help me if there is any solution, because it is very important to me. Thanks for spending your valueable time. I will still waiting for your answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation.

Comment: See also *[How to detect screen rotation through 180 degrees from landscape to landscape orientation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909037)*, which discusses teh broader question, including case when the orientation is changed programmatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) to trigger recalculation of camera rotation.

Add to your activity:

```
private OrientationEventListener orientationListener = null;
```

to `onCreate()`:

```
orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(CustomCameraActivity.this, cameraId, camera);
    }
};
```

to `surfaceCreated()`:

```
orientationListener.enable();
```

to `surfaceDestroyed()`:

```
orientationListener.disable();
```

Now, it almost works. To make `setCameraDisplayOrientation()` more robust,

1. add check for `camera != null`
2. only call `camera.setDisplayOrientation(result)` (or perform any heavy-lifting) if `result` changed since last time the function was called.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am speechless for your help. It's work fine now.

Comment: I don't like this solution. System restarts your activity and camera output is interrupted. I prefer to set fixed landscape activity orientation, and only manipulate the UI to similulate layout rotation (that's how the stock Camera app is written)

Comment: Just to add: I had to do 'orientationListener.disable();' onPause() since onDestroy is called quite some ms later (and if you press power it wont get called at all). So the bug I was getting is: rotation 90 -> home button -> rotate to 0 -> back to app -> wrong rotation

Comment: @for3st: note that the example uses `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed()` and not `Activity.onDestroy()`.

Comment: @AlexCohn yes I get that and did it in the SurfaceHolder Callback not the acitivty/fragment (sorry that was not very clear). The problem with `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed()` it does not seem to be synchronized to any onPause/onStop/etc. so in my experiments it was called when the activty was already gone and I was in the launcher. Also if you press the power-button for any reason `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed()` won't be called at all.

Comment: @for3st: It's OK to keep the camera running with black screen (after press power-button), if you still need it (for video processing or recording). But yes, if you don't use it, it is better to release it onPause() to preserve battery.

Comment: @AlexCohn the problem is, I cannot rely on `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed()` so any resouce cleaning has to be done onPause() or similar in the fragment and thus I had to do `orientationListener.disable()` in onPause()

Comment: @AlexCohn one thing to mind is, that this will get called not only on rotation change but on every degree that changes even in the same rotation-type

Comment: @for3st: that's why I advised **2** to only call `setDisplayOrientation()` (or do any heavy-lifting at all) only if `result` has changed since last time.

Comment: @AlexCohn the problem is, that on some devices when you press home and come back the roation is the same but somehow the preview reverts to default rotation, so it wont get rotated - fixable with a force rotation onResume(), but just sayin ;)

Comment: @for3st: sure, you must set `savedResult=0` in onPause

Comment: @AlexCohn, i got an error with this, some time after capturing application crashes. I  added a image of logcat when crash. plz check.

Comment: I don't know what you have at line 512, but there is some **null** hidden there.

Answer (score 1):

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

*Add this line in your Android Manifest file after declaring **all activities** in activity tags **

```
like:

<activity android:name="com.geeklabs.ActivityMain"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

May be it will helps you.