# Orientation listener globally from anywhere

Tags: android

I need something like `OrientationEventListener`. Problem with `OrientationEventListener` is that, it depends on sensor. So even if its 1 degree rotation it get called. Plus what if device doesnt have sensor but change orientation with a button. Then that method will not be called I suppose. Is there something like to listen orientation from anywhere, just need context like `OrientationEventListener` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Activity.onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) :

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //...
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        /...
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Yes but it will run in activity only. I want something like `OrientationEventListener`, you can create it anywhere, just need Context.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it is subject to quick-upside-down glitch, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532599/rotating-phone-quickly-180-degrees-camera-preview-turns-upside-down/19599599#19599599