# What's the correct way to detect a screen rotation from 0 to 180, or 90 to 270?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I'm attempting to orient a camera preview according to the screen's rotation.

I've noticed that when rotating directly between orientations with matching dimensions (so, 0 -> 180, and 90 -> 270), the configuration is not changed and the activity is not restarted.

I'm currently using `Display.getRotation()` within `Activity.onCreate()`, but this information becomes out of date.

*What's the best way to detect this change so that I can appropriately re-orient my camera preview?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`OrientationEventListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

In your SurfaceHolder.Callback

```
    orientationListener = createOrientationListener();

    private OrientationEventListener createOrientationListener() {
            return new OrientationEventListener(getActivity()) {
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                    try {
                        if (orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                            setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error while onOrientationChanged", e);
                    }
                }
            };
        }


     @Override
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         orientationListener.enable();
     }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        orientationListener.disable();
    }
```

Your change rotation method has to manage unneeded double rotations

```
public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int displayRotation) {
            int degrees = 0;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
            }

            int result;
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
            } else {  // back-facing
                result = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            if(result != currentSetRotation) {
                    currentSetRotation = result;
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
                    Log.d(TAG,"For displayRotation "+displayRotation+" we set a camera rotation of "+result);

            }
    }
```

See also: [Rotating phone quickly 180 degrees, camera preview turns upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532599/rotating-phone-quickly-180-degrees-camera-preview-turns-upside-down)