# onConfigurationChanged not called for 180 and 270 degrees

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screen-orientation

I have faced a strange issue (or maybe unexpected behavior) on my Android device.

The problem is that I am listening for configuration changes in my DialogFragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Do something secret here :)
}
```

I added `android:configChanges` to the Activity which is responsible for showing the dialog fragment

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecretActivity" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

and indeed I am getting callbacks from the system when I am rotating device, but not in all cases. As you can see in the picture `onConfigurationChanged( )` called only when I am rotating 90 degrees, and also 360, in other cases it is not called.

Is this an expected behavior?
If yes, how I can detect all rotations (90, 180, 270, 360)?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share `SecretActivity` code?

Comment: @MayurGajra sure `class SecretActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secret_activity)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }
}`

Comment: @MayurGajra it's nothing fancy just a simple activity which overrides `onConfigurationChanged `

Comment: That's really strange because I just tried that same code and it works fine for me,can you please check that in other device because it seems like an device specific issue to me.

Comment: @MayurGajra Are you really sure that when you rotate device 4 times you see 4 times `onConfigurationChanged ` called?

Comment: Yes,Just checked in Nexus 9 and Redmi 4A it worked fine,did you try setting `keyboardHidden` flag in conjunction like `orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden`?

Comment: @MayurGajra yes I tried that as well.

Comment: Did u check out this question? It looks like there is a listener for screen orientation out there! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542756/whats-the-correct-way-to-detect-a-screen-rotation-from-0-to-180-or-90-to-270

Answer (score 6):

If you have an activity with unspecified screen orientation, devices generally ignore 180° rotation and only support one landscape direction.

To support all directions, add an explicit [`screenOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation) attribute to you activity manifest entry: `user` or `sensor`, depending on whether you want to support device orientation locking by user or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: even when I am setting `user` or `sensor`still `onConfigurationChanged` is not called.

Answer (score 3):

OrientationEventlistener won't work when the device isn't rotating/moving.

I find display listener is a better way to detect the change.

```
 DisplayManager.DisplayListener mDisplayListener = new DisplayManager.DisplayListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDisplayAdded(int displayId) {
       android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Display #" + displayId + " added.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisplayChanged(int displayId) {
       android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Display #" + displayId + " changed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisplayRemoved(int displayId) {
       android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Display #" + displayId + " removed.");
    }
 };
 DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
 displayManager.registerDisplayListener(mDisplayListener, UIThreadHandler);
```

onDisplayChanged triggers only exactly when getRotation() changes. OrientationEventListener on the other hand triggers constantly in real time and even before getRotation() changes, leading to completely wrong screen rotation values when doing a 180° turn from a perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, check manifest, add this/modify

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<activity
android:name=".SecretActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

to this

```
<activity android:name=".SecretActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout|navigation"/>
```

and please checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896243/how-can-i-detect-screen-rotation/42959113) the second answer i mean.