# Camera orientation can not change with display in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I know there are already questions like this, but none solved it. I took some help and figured out basic code that I need to change the camera with respect to the display.

```
   cameraInfo=new Camera.CameraInfo();
                camera.getCameraInfo(camId,cameraInfo);
                int angle=0;
                int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getRotation();
                switch(rotation)
                {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);
                        Log.i(TAGR, "THE ROATTION IS 0");
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);
                        Log.i(TAGR, "THE ROATTION IS 90");
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);
                        Log.i(TAGR, "THE ROATTION IS 180");
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);
                        Log.i(TAGR, "THE ROATTION IS 270");
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                        break;
                    default:
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                        break;
                }

            }
```

However, I am unable to get the correct display preview with respect to the rotation of the device. I have tried several different combination of angles. However, none gave me the correct output. I am attaching the images of my preview. Please explain the solution to the problem.  Moreover, I want to know what position of my device corresponds to angles 0,90,180, and 270. In other words, is 0 corresponds to portrait or landscape orientation?.

Images :
The landscape is inverted in this one. I tried setting the rotation by 180 when ROTATION_180. Doing so did not work out, as the other orientation (in landscape) became inverted [image: The landscape in this orientation is inverted]

The upside down orientation does not do anything. The desired result is to bring the click button down with correct preview. I don't have any idea why this is not working. I have tried several values in each rotation, but none solved this issue.

[image: This is the upside down orientation of my phone]

I am a beginner, so please explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: But why you use this ? For Display Photo?

Comment: It is the camera preview that is inverted. In my app, I have a camera button to set pictures. So, the problem is with the preview.

Comment: Try ExifInterface for that.

Comment: I don't understand. How should I use .jpg interface to change my camera preview? I mean isn't it used to do stuff with .jpg files? The problem is with the camera preview. Please help

Comment: Debug your code may be your code not execute properly.

Comment: It's been 4 hours and still doing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [`CameraInfo.orientation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#orientation) for the device. Note that this property gives rotation from the natural display orientation, given for the device by [`Display.getRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29).

If your custom camera app uses [`android.hardware.camera2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API, this compensation will happen automatically.

If your custom camera activity does not lock the screen orientation, then it will be subject to "reverse landscape" glitch, and needs *[special treatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532599/rotating-phone-quickly-180-degrees-camera-preview-turns-upside-down/19599599#19599599)* which involves **OrientationEventListener**.

Comment: That worked flawlessly for the inverted portion. However, the upside down portion is still having the same problem. I tried debugging and changing the values the preview. It is changing when I put different values. So, I think the preview is fine. For Instance, I put 90 when the rotation was 270. As a result, my upside down orientation along with my landscape orientation ( corresponds to 180 degrees ) is inverted. I don't understand what is wrong with this orientation. Can you explain please? Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: Does your include `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` in **AndroidManifest.mk**?

Comment: Ha Ha! just did that and it worked like a charm. I had this "full Sensor" previously, but when I checked again it was not there. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the image like this before preview:

```
  public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bitmapSrc) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(previewRotation);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 0, 0,
            bitmapSrc.getWidth(), bitmapSrc.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

"previewRotation" can be got from:

```
    private static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Context mContext, android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info) {
    int rotation = ((CameraActivity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        previewRotation = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        previewRotation = (360 - previewRotation) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        previewRotation = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    mCameraInstance.setDisplayOrientation(previewRotation);
}
```