# Rotate camera on device rotation

Tags: android, camera, libgdx

How do I rotate a camera on device rotation?

This is what I tried to do:

```
float[] f = new float[16];
Gdx.input.getRotationMatrix( f );
Matrix4 m = new Matrix4( f );
m = m.scl( 0.01f );
cam.rotate( m );
cam.update();
```

The camera rotates waaaay too fast, but probably also not correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the full documentation on how to read and use accelerometer input?  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Accelerometer

Comment: I assume that your activity has full-sensor orientation defined in the app manifest. You can use the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532599/rotating-phone-quickly-180-degrees-camera-preview-turns-upside-down/19599599#19599599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that using the accelerometer to rotate the camera would be easier than the Rotation matrix.

If this is 2D, you would use:

```
cam.rotate(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()*SCALE);
```

This rotates the camera when you tilt the device left or right.