# know orientation of the Activity even when the app is restricted to Portrait

Tags: android, camera, screen-orientation

My app is restricted to Portrait , still I wanted to know about my Activity's orientation changes

I need this to detect whether my camera has taken picture in `Portrait mode` or `Landscape mode`

I have used `registerActivityLifecycleCallback` in `MyApplication class` to restrict the app to Portrait , still I wanted to know whether user has rotated the screen when he is in Camera Activity

CameraActivity :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
mOrientationEventListener=new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                int lastOrientation = mOrientation;

                Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                if (display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {   // landscape oriented devices

                    CAMERA_ORIENTATION = 1;
                   // methods.showToast(CameraActivity.this,"ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
                    Log.e(TAG, "onOrientationChanged: ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ");
                    Log.e(TAG, "onOrientationChanged: CAMERA_ORIENTATION  = "+CAMERA_ORIENTATION);

                    if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
                        }
                    }
                } else {  // portrait oriented devices

                    CAMERA_ORIENTATION = 0;
                    //methods.showToast(CameraActivity.this, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
                    Log.e(TAG, "onOrientationChanged: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ");
                    Log.e(TAG, "onOrientationChanged: CAMERA_ORIENTATION  = "+CAMERA_ORIENTATION);

                    if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
                        }
                    } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) {
                        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                            mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mOrientationEventListener.enable();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: are you willing to know if the taken photo was in portrait or landscape orientation ?

Comment: yes , because android itself rotates image taken in landscape :) , but also rotates image taken in portrait :(

Comment: Why don't you check the image height and width after it is taken and know if captured in landscape or in portrait ?

Comment: did ,  not any results ;(

Comment: not any results means ? width is always greater or height is always greater ?

Comment: it rotates both the landscape and portrait image

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android) answer for that problem ?

Comment: I tried this . ExifInterface always returns 0

Comment: I am really sorry bro... But thumbs up to your question !!!

Comment: Please check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19599599/192373). [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) works even when you lock the activity orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SensorManager. getOrientation to get the orientation of the device in 3D space, and then translate that into landscape or portrait.

Alternatively, if you need updates you can register for the gravity sensor and see whether gravity is measuring on the x or y axis. That won't work if the user has it flat on a tabletop, but neither will the other method.

Comment: please see my updated code .. This make my screen rotate (but wanted in Portrait )