# lock android screen orientation to landscape

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an android application whose one feature is to lock screen orientation to Landscape , I want to apply this orientation change to all the android application in phone . I am using this code

```
private void lockScreenOrientation() {
if (!mScreenOrientationLocked) {
    final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    final int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
    else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }

    mScreenOrientationLocked = true;
}
}

private void unlockScreenOrientation() {
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
 mScreenOrientationLocked = false;
}
```

But this is temporary change , doesnt take effect to all application , does anyone know a way to apply lock orientation to all applications ? Thank you

Comment: This is a guess but I'm quite sure it's impossible to lock all applications to landscape.

Comment: Have look at this app , it is working same way as i wanted https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kZXZhc3F1ZS5yb3RhdGlvbmxvY2tlciJd

Comment: I agree that you probably *shouldn't* be able to..but it apparently is possible. I use an app called Set Orientation on my Nexus 7, and it can force the system to any particular orientation.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity/3611554#3611554 and exact code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications like the one you have linked do this by modifying the global system settings values associated with rotation.  Have a look at the [Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) class for the constants available to applications.  Specifically, the `ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION` and `USER_ROTATION` values will probably be of interest.

You will also need to declare the `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` and possibly the `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permissions in your manifest.

Comment: These settings were more user friendly too compared to ``Rotation Locker`` application as this affects applications only - and most importantly - ones that do not explicitly ask for portrait mode only.

Comment: @Devunwired thank you but it actually locks the current orientation nothing else , not taking affect to other apps