# Screen orientation changes when unlock the device

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application in landscape orientation. This is how the manifest looks like:

`<activity
            android:name="Activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
</activity>`

When I lock and unlock the device the orientation changes to portrait for half of second and then goes to landscape. I noticed that this is not happening on all devices. I could reproduce it on Samsung Galaxy SI.
Any ideas what can it be?

Adding "orientation|screenSize" to configChanges does not fix the issue.

EDIT:

Basically, the layout is losing its orientation when I slide the unlock screen(specially on Samsung devices) because it's taking the orientation of the slide activity which is portrait.

Comment: What if you try to lock it using code. Check out this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266315/lock-android-screen-orientation-to-landscape

Comment: I'm not sure if I need that, I only want to get rid of the half second when the screen loses landscape orientation after unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of the layout folder to "layout-land" may fix this by only allowing drawing in landscape

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below properties in the activity tag of manifest you want,,,rather than adding your application tag

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example,MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

Or if this do not work,,, then add this code just below the setContentView() in your Activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: I had added it in activity tag, not in application tag, but it did not made any difference.

Comment: I have tried with setRequestedOrientation, but it did not worked. Please see my edit.