# Android: Detect Device Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-orientation

In my application, I need to be informed when the orientation of the android device changes. I found two approaches to do that:

1. Listen to onConfigurationChanged - Using this approach, I get the event when the phone changes from portrait to landscape and vice versa, but I do not get an event when the device changes from 90 degrees to 270 degrees - since in both the cases the orientation is still landscape.
2. Listen to onOrientationChanged (OrientationEventListener) - This event is getting fired too many times. I just need to know when the device changes between 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees. I tried using various values for "rate".

Is there third way to achieve what I want? I can share the code if required.

Comment: have u seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8450316/1289716)

Comment: again - i will NOT get any configuration changed event if i turn my device from 90 to 270 degrees.

Comment: Dear it`s Device In Built functionality so i never can manage this.in FunBook Device give us for orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by handling the events from OrientationEventListener. It fires too many times for comfort but it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT )
```

use this configuration class and get the run time device orientation

Comment: as i already mentioned, i dont get a configuration changed event when i move from 90 to 270 degrees. How does your solution solve that problem?

Comment: Just mention it this code working in change the proper  orientation  then detect the effect ok..

Answer (score 0):

if the client insists on testing on old android:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        location.reload();
    }, false);
</script>
```

wakawakawaka