# SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT is correct?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Well I'm trying to add a lock orientation button, but when I call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

the screen goes to normal portrait. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    x = event.values[0];
    y = event.values[1];
    z = event.values[2];

    orientation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (x > 5){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (x < -5){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (y > 5){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (y < -5){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: altough not exactly what you want, it has some interesting code snippets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it changing

```
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

to this

```
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

in the manifest, I don't really think that this was the problem, but now its working. Just wanted to post it in case anyone have the issue.

Comment: I face the same issue on Android KitKat however it is working great on Gingerbread !!

Comment: It looks like the SDK have some bugs then

Comment: Same issue for me, but changing targetSdkVersion didn't do it. Running KitKat.

Comment: Check if your device have any settings to enable that orientation.