# Kindle Fire orientation lock programmatically

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, kindle

I add the following line to my Activity in the Android manifest

```
 android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

then I add the below code to onCreate() in my Java class

```
 if (isSmartphone(this))
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
 else
    {
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

But in the Kindle Fire devices it's not setting the orientation. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: In menifest change like that orientation  android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: thanks.. but I need both orientations. if the device is Smart Phone the orientation should be portrait. if it is a tab the orientation should be landscape..  This is working fine except kindle fire devices

Comment: You will also need to declare the android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS and possibly the android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions in your manifest.

Comment: I think this is what you were looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20714828/1807627