# Make screenOrientation configurable?

Tags: android, orientation, android-manifest

My activity forces portrait mode using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest. However, some of my users (on tablets that are by default in landscape mode) have asked me to make this a configurable option. Is it possible to set the orientation in code (without triggering an orientation-change animation, so before the activity is actually displayed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply call:

```
 Activity.setRequestedOrientation (int requestedOrientation)
```

Taken from

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29

If you want to lock the screen orientation after setting it, take a look at this post:

> [Screen orientation lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock)

Comment: Awesome, Phil, thanks for your answer, it works beautifully :)!