# Get current orientation and lock

Tags: java, android, orientation

I'm trying to get the current orientation of an activity and lock it like this but it just goes to portrait even when opened in landscape mode.

```
//getRequestedOrientation();
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have screen orientation locked, it will show your app in portrait mode, you should use screen orientation sensor.

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Edit.

```
int str = 0;
    try {
            str = Settings.System.getInt(contexto.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION);
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {          
                e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    if(str!=0) 
    {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);   
    }
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock) link, I think it can help you.

Comment: I want it to sense the orientation and stay on the orientation even when titled.

Comment: I'm not sure what the first part of the code is doing with the Settings. I just tried it, it still changes orientation to portrait even when I clicked the app on landscape.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```